# Format of DateTime field not recognized by Spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp, datetime, spring-mvc

I am developing web application using Spring 3.2.4. I have some forms with fields containing date and time. Piece of my jsp:

```
<form:form method="post" action="/add" modelAttribute="licence">
    ...
    <form:input type="datetime" path="beginDate"/>
    <form:input type="datetime" path="endDate"/>
    <form:input path="quantityLimit"/>
    ...
</form:form>
```

Normal form, nothing fancy. I am using datepicker, which gives me date in format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm`, so I've added this to my controller:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder webDataBinder) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
    dateFormat.setLenient(true);
    webDataBinder.registerCustomEditor(DateTime.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
}
```

Also, I have added `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` to my servlet configuration xml, as stated on some blogs.

There's target controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{softwareId}/licence/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addLicence(@PathVariable("softwareId") Long softwareId, Licence licence, Model model) {
    Software software = softwareRepository.findOne(softwareId);
    licence.setSoftware(software);
    licenceRepository.save(licence);
    return ADMIN_PATH + "softwareEdit";
}
```

And software class looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "licences")
public class Licence {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "begin_date")
private DateTime beginDate;

@Column(name = "end_date")
private DateTime endDate;

@Column(name = "quantity_limit")
private Long quantityLimit;

@ManyToOne
private Software software;

//getters, setters, etc.
}
```

The problem is: when I submit my form with dateTime field empty it works perfectly, but when I have anything in date field (no matter if it's properly formatted or not) I get `HTTP Error 400: Bad Request`. No exceptions in console, only bad request, but I am pretty sure it has something to do with date parsing.

Is there a well described method of dealing with date and time fields in forms in Spring applications?

Comment: Set your logging to DEBUG. Spring will tell you what's up. Also, show us your command class.

Comment: Use firebug and see the "Net" tab and see the outgoing parameters, you might get some clue.

Comment: So, logging on DEBUG level shows literally nothing when form has been sent.
Also, net tab in Chrome, Firefox and Safari shows normal POST with all fields.

Comment: That's not possible. Check your loggers. Spring will always log something when it responds with 400.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make your life simple and use `@DateTimeFormat`, getting rid of your `WebDataBinder` configuration. It seems `CustomDateEditor` only works with `java.util.Date` and Spring has no other (default/not-specified) mechanism to convert from a `String` to a `DateTime`.

[`@DateTimeFormat`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html) is such a mechanism.

```
@Column(name = "begin_date")
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
private DateTime beginDate;
```